# Loop a short python script that parses data from a json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, python-requests

I hope the title makes sense, english is not my first language and somewhat i have no idea if i wrote it right..
Basically i have a python scripts that i use for phishing sites, to spam them with random data.
I have the .py file and a .json file.

app.py:

```
import requests
import os
import random
import string
import json

chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'
random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))

url = 'site/file.php'

names = json.loads(open('names.json').read())

for name in names:
    name_extra = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits))

    username = name.lower() + name_extra + '@yahoo.com'
    password = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(12))

    requests.post(url, allow_redirects=False, data={
        'login': username,
        'pass': password
    })

    print ('sending username %s and password %s' % (username, password))
```

The json has a couple random names:

```
[
"Liam",
"Noah",
"William"
]
```

In my names.json i have about 40 random names, everytime i start the program it will go through all the 40 names and then it will just close..
Is there any way for me to loop infinitely through the names? And make the program run 24/7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly want it to run forever (or until you end it), you can use

```
while(True):
    print("This will go forever")
```

It's unclear which part you want to run forever, but in your case this would look something like

```
while(True):
    for name in names:
        name_extra = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits))

        username = name.lower() + name_extra + '@yahoo.com'
        password = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(12))

        requests.post(url, allow_redirects=False, data={
            'login': username,
            'pass': password
        })

        print ('sending username %s and password %s' % (username, password))
```